# check existing list items else add item

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

i need to check the list for duplicate items from user input.

so if "Usa" is input and the again , an error will appear saying thats invalid

add is connected to a button:

The Add section is where its broken , it displays all but fails after the messagebox has popped up.

ive tried using both try and if statements but my main issue is im not sure where the input from text.listwidget is stored

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QInputDialog, QDialog, QLineEdit, QMessageBox ,QLabel


class Window(QDialog):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(580, 600)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(15, 15, 15, 15)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSpacing(6)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(15, 15, 15, 15)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(6)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(Dialog)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(15, 15, 15, 15)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(6)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.pushButton_add = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_add.setObjectName("pushButton_add")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_add)
        self.pushButton_edit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_edit.setObjectName("pushButton_edit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_edit)
        self.pushButton_remove = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_remove.setObjectName("pushButton_remove")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_remove)
        self.pushButton_up = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_up.setObjectName("pushButton_up")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_up)
        self.pushButton_down = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_down.setObjectName("pushButton_down")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_down)
        self.pushButton_sort = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_sort.setObjectName("pushButton_sort")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_sort)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.pushButton_close = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_close.setObjectName("pushButton_close")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_close)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_add.clicked.connect(self.add)
        self.pushButton_edit.clicked.connect(self.edit)
        self.pushButton_remove.clicked.connect(self.remove)
        self.pushButton_up.clicked.connect(self.up)
        self.pushButton_down.clicked.connect(self.down)
        self.pushButton_sort.clicked.connect(self.sort)
        self.pushButton_close.clicked.connect(self.close)

        self.label_1 = QLabel(self)
        self.label_1.setText("Enter a country: ")
        self.label_1.move(10, 580)
        self.label_1.resize(280, 40)

        self.Country()

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Covid country"))
        Dialog.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icon.png"))
        self.pushButton_add.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Add"))
        self.pushButton_edit.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Edit"))
        self.pushButton_remove.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Remove"))
        self.pushButton_up.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Up"))
        self.pushButton_down.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Down"))
        self.pushButton_sort.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Sort"))
        self.pushButton_close.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Close"))

    def Country(self):

        self.country = []
        self.listWidget.addItems(self.country)
        self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(0)

    def add(self):
        row = self.listWidget.currentRow()
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Country", "Enter country")
        texts = self.listWidget.items()
        if ok and text is not None:
            self.listWidget.insertItem(row, text)
        if texts in self.listWidget.items():
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)
            msg.setText("No country selected.")
            msg.setWindowTitle("Error")
            msg.exec_()
            return


    def edit(self):
        row = self.listWidget.currentRow()
        item = self.listWidget.item(row)

        if item is not None:
            string, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Country Dialog", "Edit Country",
                                              QLineEdit.Normal, item.text())
            if ok and string is not None:
                item.setText(string)

    def remove(self):
        row = self.listWidget.currentRow()
        item = self.listWidget.item(row)

        if item is None:
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)
            msg.setText("No country selected.")
            msg.setWindowTitle("Error")
            msg.exec_()
            return

        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, "Remove Country", "Do You Want To Remove Country " + str(item.text()),
                                     QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            item = self.listWidget.takeItem(row)
            del item

    def up(self):
        row = self.listWidget.currentRow()
        if row >= 1:
            item = self.listWidget.takeItem(row)
            self.listWidget.insertItem(row - 1, item)
            self.listWidget.setCurrentItem(item)

    def down(self):
        row = self.listWidget.currentRow()
        if row < self.listWidget.count() - 1:
            item = self.listWidget.takeItem(row)
            self.listWidget.insertItem(row + 1, item)
            self.listWidget.setCurrentItem(item)

    def sort(self):
        self.listWidget.sortItems()

    def close(self):
        quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Window()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how do i check that the input isnt an existing item on the list , throw out an error if it is . if not , add the item to the list

Comment: So in what way is the existing code unsatisfactory? I presume you've run it and see some untoward behaviour still currently unknown to us readers. You might like to add some explanation to the question.

Comment: it doesnt do it and im not sure why 

the app opens, i click add , input and click okay , then failure

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproductible example. We cannot run your sample code.

Comment: see my full code below :)

Comment: The answer section is for answers, if you want to add more information like the [MRE] then edit your question and put it there

Comment: sorry , was unaware , ive editted my question to display the full code . hopefully it will provide more context

Answer (score 0):

The line `self.listWidget.items()` is not for getting all the items.

> Returns a list of pointers to the items contained in the data object. If the object was not created by a QListWidget in the same process, the list is empty.

To get all the items inside you could solve it like in the [previously answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571706/how-to-list-all-items-from-qlistwidget)

```
items = []
for x in range(self.listWidget.count()-1):
    items.append(self.listWidget.item(x))
```

I would also use [QListWidget.findItems(text, flags)](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QListWidget.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QListWidget.findItems)

```
def add(self):
    row = self.listWidget.currentRow()
    text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Country", "Enter country")
    if ok and text is not None:
        items = self.listWidget.findItems(text,QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly)
        if not items:
            self.listWidget.insertItem(row, text)
        else:
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)
            msg.setText("No country selected.")
            msg.setWindowTitle("Error")
            msg.exec_()
            return
```